# Tampermonkey Click This Button

Tags: javascript

I have spend the last day trying to auto click this button to no avail. The source for the button is this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success ng-binding" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="saveButton.disabled">Save</button>
```

The button only pops up after a couple of button clicks so I have been looping my scripts just in case.

My first solution (which returns a whole bunch of errors with reloading):

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("save()")[0].click();
});
```

And my second one (which does nothing):

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success ng-binding")[0].click();
});
```

I will keep trying different stuff while hopefully waiting for an answer and will update if I find something that works.

Comment: Can you post the javascript that you have tried for this?

Comment: $(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("save()")[0].click();
}); Which returns a whole bunch of errors with reloading.

Comment: $(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success ng-binding")[0].click();
}); Which does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution doesn't work because `save()` is not a class name of your button, so [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return an empty array whose first element is of course undefined, so it doesn't have a `click()` function.

Your second solution works perfectly fine. I added a click listener to the button and then your solution. As you can see, the event is fired and the alert in the event listener is displayed.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success ng-binding")[0].onclick = function() {
  alert('Button clicked!');
};
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success ng-binding")[0].click();
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success ng-binding" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="saveButton.disabled">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I also found that this work too. $( "button[class='btn btn-success ng-binding']" ).click(); but I think I'll use yours.

Comment: @BrandonHellman Yes there are multiple ways to write a selector:)